# how to disable ag-grid live sort after sorting a column

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid react in my application. I have data that changes frequently. When sorting a column I want the rows to freeze by the last sort. The default behavior of the gird is to keep sorting when there are new updates.

It's very confusing. Couldn't find any option to do that.